# UnboundID LDAP - how to set flags in userAccountControl attribute

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

i am using UnboundID LDAP SDK for ActiveDirectory management, and i want to create new user. I am  able to create connection to ActiveDirectory and add new user with some attributes, but i dont know how to work with attribute userAccountControl. This attribute is used by ActiveDirectory to store some flags, and i don't know how to set these flags using UnboundID LDAP SDK. Thank for any help.

Some information about attribute userAccountControl
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680832(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found out that i had some path wrong, here is code for modification userAccountControl

```
Modification mod = new Modification(ModificationType.REPLACE, "userAccountControl", usr.getUAC().toString());
ModifyRequest req = new ModifyRequest(userCN + userOU, mod);
LDAPResult modResult = connection.modify(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

The userAccountControl is a bit mask so it is necessary to set is as an integer.

We have some of the values and information documented here:
http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/User-Account-Control%20Attribute%20Values

Might help if you said what you were trying to set in userAccountControl and provided the  code you are using.

Comment: thank for response, i found out that problem was some wrong path :)